# Email not sending using SMTP in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, email, smtp, smtpclient

I am try to send email through SMTP in ASP.net but email not sending and not giving any error. My code:

```
//create the mail message
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
//set the FROM address
mail.From = new MailAddress("aaa@abc.com");
//set the RECIPIENTS
mail.To.Add("bbb@abc.com");
//enter a SUBJECT
mail.Subject = "Set the subject of the mail here.";
//Enter the message BODY
mail.Body = "Enter text for the e-mail here.";
//set the mail server (default should be smtp.1and1.com)
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.1and1.com");
//Enter your full e-mail address and password
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("example@abc.com", "xxxxxxx");
//send the message 
smtp.Send(mail);
```

And my code in web.config is

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
        <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\Mail\" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" />
  </system.net>
```

Comment: your smtp port might be blocked or the credentials might be wrong

Answer (score 1):

Use breakpoint to display each parameter's value. Even if there is no error in the codes, parameter's value may be null or wrong. Before breakpoint, use try-catch as it below;

```
                try
                {
                    // Your codes
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception(ex.Message.ToString());
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check First you TLS Version.
Open your Site in IE(Internet Explorer) browser and go to page properties.

[image]

If your TLS 1.2 then  Add below code before client.Send(Object);

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

like as per bellow

```
 System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient objSMTPClient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
 SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
 client.EnableSsl = true;
 ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
 ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
 client.Send(oMail);
 client.Dispose();
 client = null;
```